# How do I solve the equivalent resistance of this circuit?

Tags: resistors, resistance

How do I determine the equivalent resistance of the circuit looking into terminals A and B? I am quite stuck and the only thing I've figured out is that there are 3 pairs of parallel resistors: 90&12, 18&6, 100&150. The diagonal wires with no resistors kind of throw me off.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: My Solution]

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here. We need you to show us that you have done a substantial amount of work yourself, show us everything that you have done, then ask a **specific** question. Why don't you start by labeling all of the nodes in the schematic?

Comment: There was a very similar question here couple of days ago, just the diagonal lines were arranged differently. Was it your question? Can't you apply the similar technique to it?

Comment: Yes but where are you stuck and why do the diagonals throw you off? Redraw the circuit without diagonals then.

Comment: I've added a photo to my post to show my attempt at simplifying the circuit. I tried to research how to do it and I found a similar circuit with no empty wires and I tried to pattern it out of that. I just don't know where to go from there. Maybe you could point me in a direction.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It wasn't my question and I'm new to the platform, could you maybe share the link to it. Thank you

Comment: @Holyyy, remember that any two nodes without a resistor between them can be merged. You still have two more nodes to merge before you can calculate using basic serial and parallel resistance equations.

Comment: @Holyyy Here it is: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554120/how-do-i-simplify-and-calculate-the-resistance-this-circuit looks like the problem from the very same book/course.

Comment: @user8908459 oh so does that mean the 3-ohm, 4.5-ohm,10.59-ohm, and 60-ohm resistors are all parallel to each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i simplify and calculate the resistance this circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554120/how-do-i-simplify-and-calculate-the-resistance-this-circuit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving the image only. The members may frown.
Only 2 nodes are there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Redraw the circuit.

Start by putting the node labels "A" & "B" on all nodes that connect directly to the input terminals.

Then draw the circuit with all of the resistors parallel to each other where possible.  Obviously, have all of the node "A" ends of the resistors at the top (or bottom) and all of the node "B" ends of the resistors at the opposite end.

The solution should be fairly obvious when you have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonal lines means the circuit becomes short. To the right of the circuit branch current will not flow due to circuit been short. Only on left to the short circuit current will flow. Circuit becomes now easy to solve.